# Django JSONField update on Postgres fails with: "value too long for type character varying(60)"

Tags: python, django, postgresql

It's my first time asking a question, so I hope I don't break any major rules.

Everything works fine locally on SQLite, but not on production with PostgreSQL. Django says their JSONField uses [jsonb by default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#jsonfield), which translates to roughly 250MB.

Model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_jsonfield = models.JSONField(default=dict, blank=True)
    ...
```

Serializer:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['my_jsonfield']
```

Existing data on that field looks like this (possibly already exceeding 60 chars):

```
[
 ["item_1", 1617706749],
 ["item_2", 1617706749],
 ["item_3", 1617706749]
]
```

The error happens while I try save the serializer, something like:

```
new_item = ["item_4", 1617708548]
old_item = list(instance.my_jsonfield)

combine_items = {"my_jsonfield" : old_item + new item}
serializer = MySerializer(instance, data=combine_items, partial=True)

if serializer.is_valid(): 
     serializer.save() # <--- ERROR HERE
```

I have already tried deleting all migrations and `manage.py migrate <app_name> zero` + played around with field options.

**What else am I missing here?**

Python 3.8.5; Django 3.1.2; djangorestframework 3.12.1; PostgreSQL 12

Comment: show model and serializer

Comment: I've edited the post. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it will solve all your issues but one of the mistakes you made is passing `combine_items` as `data` to your serializer. It should be a `dict` with key corresponding to serializer field name.

```
serializer = MySerializer(instance, data={"my_jsonfield": combine_items})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry, I overlooked it when I was typing up the question. It's not the issue, since I'm having an error on serializer.save() after it's validated.

Comment: It is an issue as you have `blank=True` on `my_jsonfield` which is the only field in your serializer and you haven't passed it so basically there's nothing to validate.

Comment: I've edited the question as per your answer originally. I have been passing a dict to the serializer all along and it works like a charm locally, so I'm still suspecting something other than my model or a serializer. Perhaps Django's config on JSONField for PostgreSQL.

Comment: It's definitely your migrations.

Comment: I've deleted them and migrated back to initial and this has no effect. What do you recommend?

Comment: inspect database tables on production and local env. Are you sure you run all the necessary migrations on prod?

Answer (score 0):

After inspecting like crazy, I discovered a bug in the same function above where I had altered an another field of `MyModel` thru `instance.other_field = "some_large_value"`. To no surprise, this field was `models.CharField(max_length=60)` and the cause of the error that popped up when it was trying to save the serializer. For the field that I initially thought was causing the error, it was indeed jsonb and the migrations had been applied.

Lesson learned.

Thanks, Tom, for suggestions!